# Are there something like Python generators in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, lazy-evaluation

I am new to Ruby, is there a way to `yield` values from Ruby functions? If yes, how? If not, what are my options to write lazy code?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Ruby's `yield` keyword is something very different from the Python keyword with the same name, so don't be confused by it. Ruby's `yield` keyword is syntactic sugar for calling a block associated with a method.

The closest equivalent is Ruby's Enumerator class. For example, the equivalent of the Python:

```
def eternal_sequence():
  i = 0
  while True:
    yield i
    i += 1
```

is this:

```
def eternal_sequence
  Enumerator.new do |enum|
    i = 0
    while true
      enum.yield i # <- Notice that this is the yield method of the enumerator, not the yield keyword
      i +=1
    end
  end
end
```

You can also create Enumerators for existing enumeration methods with `enum_for`. For example, `('a'..'z').enum_for(:each_with_index)` gives you an enumerator of the lowercase letters along with their place in the alphabet. You get this for free with the standard Enumerable methods like `each_with_index` in 1.9, so you can just write `('a'..'z').each_with_index` to get the enumerator.

Comment: `0.step` is an eternal enumerator since 1.9

Answer (score 26):

I've seen [Fibers](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/Fiber.html) used in that way, look at an example from [this article](http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/08/ruby-1-9-fibers):

```
fib = Fiber.new do  
  x, y = 0, 1 
  loop do  
    Fiber.yield y 
    x,y = y,x+y 
  end 
end 
20.times { puts fib.resume }
```

Comment: In fact, in Ruby 1.9's `Enumerator` is implemented using `Fiber`. That was one of the main reasons for adding them, actually, because in Ruby 1.8 `Enumerator`s use continuations, but that is a) rather unwieldy and b) at that time continuations were going to be removed from the Ruby language.

Answer (score 15):

If you are looking to lazily generate values, @Chuck's answer is the correct one.

If you are looking to lazily iterate over a collection, Ruby 2.0 introduced the new `.lazy` enumerator.

```
range = 1..Float::INFINITY
puts range.map { |x| x+1 }.first(10) #  infinite loop
puts range.lazy.map { |x| x+1 }.first(10) #  [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Answer (score 7):

Ruby supports generators out of the box using `Enumerable::Generator`:

```
require 'generator'

# Generator from an Enumerable object
g = Generator.new(['A', 'B', 'C', 'Z'])

while g.next?
  puts g.next
end

# Generator from a block
g = Generator.new { |g|
  for i in 'A'..'C'
    g.yield i
  end

  g.yield 'Z'
}

# The same result as above
while g.next?
  puts g.next
end
```

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/generator/rdoc/Generator.html

Answer (score 0):

Class `Enumerator` and its method `next` behave similar
https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-next

```rb
range = 1..Float::INFINITY
enumerator = range.each

puts enumerator.class # => Enumerator

puts enumerator.next  # => 1
puts enumerator.next  # => 2
puts enumerator.next  # => 3
```