# Yield all values from another iterator

Tags: ruby

Does Ruby provide any mechanism to allow an iterator to `yield` all values from another iterator? (or "subiterator", I'm not sure what the proper name is).  Similar to Python3.3+'s [yield from](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/#motivation)

```
def f
    yield 'a'
    yield 'b'
end

def g
   # yield everything from f
   yield 'c'
   yield 'd'
end
```

Comment: `f { |x| yield x }` too long? :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson if `f` yields multiple values it starts to be

Comment: though I suppose {|*x| yield x} be okay but idk if there are any subtleties to that I'm missing.  But I was looking for something that handles all the things that can happen in normal interactions with iterators (exceptions and whatnot) without anything special

Comment: `yield` means and does [something different](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504494/are-there-something-like-python-generators-in-ruby) in both languages.

Comment: I was not aware that yield was equivalent to just calling the block, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably the most idiomatic approach:

```
def f
  yield 'a'
  yield 'b'
end

def g(&block)
  f(&block)
  yield 'c'
  yield 'd'
end
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is this:

```
def f
  yield 'a'
  yield 'b'
end

def g
 f &Proc.new # 'duplicate' the block given to g and pass it to f
 yield 'c'
 yield 'd'
end
```

Comment: I had no idea that was possible. Can you give some reference? why `Proc.new` is the duplicate of the block and not an empty proc? it looks somewhat cryptic at first sight.

Comment: The [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Proc.html#method-c-new) specify this behaviour :).

Comment: That's sad because I searched the docs, read those lines, and failed to connect the dots :-( I am afraid that's just too implicit for my taste. I don't recall finding code that uses "feature" either, so I guess I am not the only one. It perfectly answers the question, though, so +1

Comment: Anyone interested in the use of `&` above should check out: http://ablogaboutcode.com/2012/01/04/the-ampersand-operator-in-ruby/

Comment: comparing this to @tokland's answer.  Does tokland's avoid duplication of the block, or does the `&block` create a new `Proc` object as well? (Ruby's far from my strongest language)

Comment: @Ryan I tested that just now. It seems like neither methods duplicate the block. The blocks have same hash.